# Creating single row pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this-

```
                 0
0            a  43
1            b  630
2            r  587
3            i  462
4            g  153
5            t  266
```

I want to create a new dataframe which looks like this-

```
     a         b     r       i     g        t
0    43       630   587    462    153      266
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just one column with this format `a 43`, this should work:

```
df.columns = ['col']
df = pd.DataFrame(df.col.str.split(' ',1).tolist(), columns = ['col1','col2']).T.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])
```

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
     ['a 43',],
     ['b 630'],
     ['r 587']],
columns=['col'])

     col
0   a 43
1  b 630
2  r 587
```

Output:

```
    a    b    r
1  43  630  587
```

Comment: my column name is 0 by default...what changes to be made?

Comment: Here `df.col.str.split` instead of `col` the name of your columns. try with df[0] or df['0']

Comment: Or even better, add this line: `df.columns = ['col']` I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can transpose your dataframe via `df.T` or `df.transpose()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3], ['D', 4], ['E', 5]],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2'])

print(df)

  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    B     2
2    C     3
3    D     4
4    E     5

res = df.set_index('col1').T
```

Result:

```
print(res)

col1  A  B  C  D  E
col2  1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: I agree... however it's a little unclear whether the OP does actually have two columns or whether it's one column that needs processing to transpose on... I have a feeling (probably wrong) they need to split that column to get the names, then just pivot the result...

Comment: @JonClements, Hmm, I see. I just took OP's question very literally. Will update if more is required.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2d array by list comprehension with split and then new `Dataframe` by constructor:

```
a = np.array([x.split() for x in df['0']])

df = pd.DataFrame([a[:, 1]], columns=a[:, 0])
print (df)
    a    b    r    i    g    t
0  43  630  587  462  153  266
```